# My application won't launch giving me some random error error when I haven't touched anything

Tags: c#, wpf, startup, program-entry-point

I'm having trouble debugging my application because I can't even run it.
I haven't changed anything only added a picture to a folder in my solution explorer and now I can't even press F5 to debug it.

Here's the error:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
>   was unhandled
>   Message=" Can't create instance of 'MainWindow' in the assembly.'testapp1
>   v0.1[WPF], Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  Error in markup file 'MainWindow.xaml' Line 1
>   Position 9."
>   Source="PresentationFramework"
>   LineNumber=1   LinePosition=9

I know this isn't much information but I'd really like to know if there is something clear I should be looking for. This is the first something like this has happened to me.

---

**Edit:** Here's the First lines of XAML code which are supposedly breaking my app.

```
<Window x:Class="Testapp1.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Tome of Newerth" Height="700" Width="900">
```

Comment: Can you post some code? MainWindow.xaml and MainWindow.xaml.cs - assuming they aren't too big of course.

Comment: They are pretty big, about 1300 lines. All of it is just control and grid declarations with Click events and nothing else. No themes, or anything too advanced because I'm just learning WPF. This is just so disheartening to happen especially when I've done so much work on the app. I'm afraid I'll lose all progress now. Sure I have backups, but I've done so much since the previous working backup. Please help!

Comment: What's the InnerException? http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/03/14/108728.aspx

Comment: Yeah, removed picture (.jpg) from Solution explorer and it still gives this exception.

Comment: DTB: Your link saved me TONS AND TONS of work. After drilling down the View Detail and finding the inner exception it turns out I have an XML node with two "<" and that was breaking my app. Thanks a million my brother.

Comment: Source control could have been of help in finding what broke this and when.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you remove the picture? Does it work again?

From the code you've posted it indicates that the error is in the code behind as it can't create an instance of the class.

What does the constructor of your `MainWindow` class look like.

Comment: That's the thing. I've added countless other pictures to the solution explorer on this same app and never broke. Now something has happened that broke it completely. I don't know what it is.